# Getting only the first snapshot of the scans with gmapping

Tags: navigation, gmapping, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I've gone through one that seems to be a shared problem, as the following links testify

- http://answers.ros.org/question/218227/how-to-create-map-with-gmapping/
- http://answers.ros.org/question/32399/slam_gmapping-registering-first-scan-problem/
- http://answers.ros.org/question/200870/gmapping-calculate-only-first-laser-scan/

Some of them didn't received a satisfactory answers, while the successful replies to the others are not working for me.
I'm trying to make a map with an iRobot Create 2, using the `irobotcreate2ros` node (https://github.com/MirkoFerrati/irobotcreate2ros), and using a Kinect as a sensor (from which I take the laser scan using the `depth2laser` node https://github.com/mauriliodc/depth2laser). I changed the tf published by the irobotcreate2ros node, so that the frames are directly `odom` and `base_link`, instead of `iRobot_0/odom` and `iRobot_0/base_link` (as in the original version), and then I don't need a static_transformation_publisher (it shouldn't affect the general behavior, I suppose).

What happen is that when I start `gmapping`, it seems to take only the first snapshot from the sensor, showing a small segment of the map, and not updating it while the robot moves. I tried both to see the realtime mapping in rviz and to try with a rosbag, but the result is always the same.

The following picture shows a snapshot or what I see in rviz

[Rviz snaptshot](https://imageshack.com/i/porEiqH3p)

And the following picture instead shows my tfs (that are supposed to be correct, as far as I know)

[View_frames output](http://imageshack.com/a/img924/7184/K9hzrG.jpg)

I already checked that my odometry, the base_link, the xtion and the laser tf are consistent with each other (as they move accordingly in rviz). I've also a bag, but I cannot yet upload it. I'm searching a space where to do it. As soon as I find it, I'll edit this post.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/229881/getting-only-the-first-snapshot-of-the-scans-with-gmapping/) by [McKracken82](https://answers.ros.org/users/26321/mckracken82/) on ROS Answers with karma: 73 on 2016-03-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Solution found. The problem was a bug in the `depth2laser` node. When publishing the laser, the time field in the header was always set to 0, so that was impossible to reconstruct the time sequence of the scans. After having fixed that, `gmapping` was working correctly. I already informed the author of the node about the bug, and it should be now fixed.

---

Originally posted by [McKracken82](https://answers.ros.org/users/26321/mckracken82/) with karma: 73 on 2016-03-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Icehawk101](https://answers.ros.org/users/4327/icehawk101/) on 2016-03-23**:
Good work! If it works now, you should close the thread and select this as the correct answer.